# For Loops in ThymeLeaf Views

Tags: for-loop, spring-boot, web, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am looking to use a for loop in my ThymeLeaf view.

I have a list model holding 8 objects.

I would like to loop objects though 1 to 4 in one area and from 5 to 8 in another.

Can this be done?

Is there a way of manipulating a for each loop to suit my application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should probably use the [#numbers](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers) utility object.  Something like this, for example:

```html
<span th:each="n: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 4)}" th:text="${n}" />
<span th:each="n: ${#numbers.sequence(5, 8)}" th:text="${n}" />
```

(These two blocks will print 1 through 4 and 5 through 8, respectively.)  Your list (if named list), would look like this:

```html
<span th:each="n: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 4)}" th:text="${list[n].fieldOne}" />
<span th:each="n: ${#numbers.sequence(5, 8)}" th:text="${list[n].fieldTwo}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Look here http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

You can access the actual index and count variables using the `th:each` 
From there on you can read the value in the first block and stop when your count is 4. And in the second block you can add another `th:each` iterating again but only from count 5 on.